# Efficient data-structure to searching data only in documents a user can access

Tags: caching, search, data-structures, permissions, inverted-index

**Problem description:**

The goal is to efficiently query strings from a set of JSON documents while respecting document-level security, such that a user is only able to retrieve data from documents they have access to.

Suppose we have the following documents:

Document `document_1`, which has no restrictions:

```
{
    "id": "document_1",
    "set_of_strings_1": [
        "the",
        "quick",
        "brown"
    ],
    "set_of_strings_2": [
        "fox",
        "jumps",
        "over",
    ],
    "isPublic": true
}
```

Document `document_2`, which can only be accessed by 3 users:

```
{
    "id": "document_2",
    "set_of_strings_1": [
        "the"
        "lazy"
    ],
    "set_of_strings_2": [
        "dog",
    ],
    "isPublic": false,
    "allowed_users": [
        "Alice",
        "Bob",
        "Charlie"
    ]
}
```

Now suppose user Bob (has access to both documents) makes the following query:

```
getStrings(
    user_id: "Bob",
    set_of_strings_id: "set_of_strings_1"
)
```

The correct response should be the union of `set_of_strings_1` from both documents:

```
["the", "quick", "brown", "lazy"]
```

Now suppose user Dave (has access to document_1 only) makes the following query:

```
getStrings(
    user_id: "Dave",
    set_of_strings_id: "set_of_strings_1"
)
```

The correct response should be `set_of_strings_1` from `document_1`:

```
["the", "quick", "brown"]
```

---

A further optimization is to handle prefix tokens. E.g. for the query

```
getStrings(
    user_id: "Bob",
    set_of_strings_id: "set_of_strings_1",
    token: "t"
)
```

The correct response should be:

```
["the"]
```

Note: empty token should match all strings.

However, I am happy to perform a simple in-memory prefix-match after the strings have been retrieved. The bottleneck here is expected to be the number of documents, not the number of strings.

---

**What I have tried:**

**Approach 1:** Naive approach

The naive solution here would be to:

- put all the documents in a SQL database
- perform a full-table scan to get all the documents (we can have millions of documents)
- iterate through all the documents to figure out user permissions
- filtering out the set of documents the user can access
- iterating through the filtered list to get all the strings

This is too slow.

**Approach 2:** Inverted indices

Another approach considered is to create an inverted index from users to documents, e.g.

| `users` | `documents_they_can_see` |
| --- | --- |
| `user_1` | `document_1, document_2, document_3` |
| `user_2` | `document_1` |
| `user_3` | `document_1, document_4` |

This will efficiently give us the document ids, which we can use against some other index to construct the string set.

If this next step is done naively, it still involves a linear scan through all the documents the user is able to access. To avoid this, we can create another inverted index mapping `document_id#set_of_strings_id` to the corresponding set of strings then we just take the union of all the sets to get the result and then we can run prefix match after. However, this involves doing the union of a large number of sets.

**Approach 3:** Caching

Use redis with the following data model:

| `key` | `value` |
| --- | --- |
| `user_id#set_of_strings_id` | `[String]` |

Then we perform prefix match in-memory on the set of strings we get from the cache.

We want this data to be fairly up-to-date so the source-of-truth datastore still needs to be performant.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Is there a data structure or some off-the-shelf system that does what I am trying to do?